# Saving card id locally - Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Currently the code is as follows.

```
hash = {
      customer: customer.id,
      amount: 50,
      description: "Purchased book #{@book.title}",
      currency: 'usd',
    }

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(hash)
```

In this case the default card stored in database will be used for payment.

Now consider that the user has two cards in stripe and user wants to make payment with the second card( which is not the default one)

As per the current code, eventhough user enters card details of second card, still the payment will be made from the default card.

**So i am planning to store card_id returned from stripe and store it along with the customer_id on local database.**

So that i can modify the code as follows.

```
hash = {
      customer: customer.id,
      amount: 50,
      description: "Purchased book #{@book.title}",
      currency: 'usd',
      card: 'Card_xxxxxxxxxx'  #specify which card to use for payment  
    }

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(hash)
```

So the questions is

> Is it a good practice to store card_id returned from stripe to store on
>   local database?

If not, what should be ideal approach for this situation?

Comment: Yes, this is entirely normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the `source` attribute of the charge. This can be a card or a token, etc.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's totally normal. This way you can reference that card without the need to meet much of [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/). You should be able to use that, with the customer_id later for other charge(s), subscription, etc.

Beware though, never log card numbers, CVV, expiry etc.